# Intermittent problems with embedded Google map on Android App

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an application that is installed on numerous devices and recently I have gotten a couple of reports that the map tiles are grey within my app.  I asked the normal questions like whether they were connected to the internet.  They seem to be connected.  Also the google maps app works.  I have looked and found no mention of these types of problems.  Any recommendations as to how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

If it works most of the time, then the problem is not with your code -- the only ways you can mess this up (e.g., no `INTERNET` permission) means it never works.

Hence, the problem is either:

- modded ROMs or devices with illicit copies of the Maps tech that are getting blocked by Google, or
- connectivity issues with the Maps server

There is nothing really for you to debug, AFAIK.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to override the INTERNET permission request on a per app basis without any funky messages coming up with the app is launched?

Comment: @Tim: Not in standard Android.